# How to run command: python manage.py makemigrations in arbitrary order?

Tags: python

**When I run the command `python manage.py makemigrations` models are created in alphabetical order:**

```
Migrations for 'UserInfo':
  UserInfo\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Address
    - Create model AttPhoto
    - Create model Bank
    - Create model CurriculumVitae
    - Create model CVApply
    - Create model Experiences
    - Create model Insurance
    - Create model JobApply
    - Create model Jobs
    - Create model Languages
    - Create model PhotoCard
    - Create model Schedule
    - Create model Shift
    - Create model ShiftInOut
    - Create model TaxCode
    - Create model Wallet
    - Create model UserInfo
    - Create model Location
    - Create model InOutArr
    - Create model InOut
    - Create model InFoCheckinout
    - Create model Educate
    - Create model Company
    - Create model CheckInOut
```

**Problem:**

**I want it to be created with an arbitrary order I pick** :

```
As you can see it is running in alphabetical order: a, b, c, ... not the way I want to sort the models, that affects foreign keys.
```

**If anything is stupid please ignore** :Thanks very much!

Comment: Since you explictly run `python manage.py makemigrations`, you are already creating it at your disposal. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: As you can see it is running in alphabetical order: a, b, c, ... not the way I want to sort the models, that affects foreign keys.

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem, but you can just re-order the models in the migration file.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this does *not *affect the foreign keys. It is inside your `models.py` (or whichever file you use to define your models) where it is affected. You can forward-declare foreign keys in Django by using a string instead of the model class itself.

Comment: I don't see an actual problem here. You mention one, but you don't show how it affects your code or running program. Unless you can clarify what actually goes wrong, I think this question can remain closed, since there is no problem; perhaps just a misunderstanding, but at the moment, that potential misunderstanding is unclear as well.

Answer (score 1):

Typically if a tool orders script alphabetically, the "general" approach is to add your specific ordering to the name, like in Unix initialisation scripts, i.e.:

```
01_do_this_first.sh
02_then_do_this.sh
03_finally_do_this.sh
```